# Nested tooltip (tooltip within tooltip)

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I have a page which is having some link and when i click on that link it open a tool tip form that also contains some link and now i want to open another form within already opened tool tip. Is there any possible way? Please help.

Comment: I suspect it's possible, certainly using jQuery/JS, but I'd suggest that if your *tooltip* (intended as an explanatory note of some kind) needs a tooltip, you're not explaining yourself clearly enough. This is technically interesting, but it seems *functionally* unwise or unwieldy.

Comment: Are you using a specific jquery plugin? URL to it? Sample code?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem yesterday. What I realized is that a tooltip is a very specific thing and you are not supposed to show two tooltips at once or nest them. In my case, displaying the second tooltip closed the container and none was visible.
My solution was to replace the container tooltip with a JQuery UI dialog which made more sense and then use the tooltips inside.